# Eclipse plug-in o3smeasures is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I need to use the following plug-in in a school project: https://mariazevedo88.github.io/o3smeasures/

I successfully added the plug-in to Eclipse, but I am unable to see the right click option on my projects, it does not show up.

The plug-in is installed, because I am able to add the plug-in views.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it many times, and tried Eclipse 2020-09 and Eclipse 2020-06 (should work with the 2020-06)

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy your project into a new workspace. Something went wrong in your workspace.